# Как модифицировать sql запрос?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE Emp ( 
  DEPTNO Int,
  SALARY Int,
  Name varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO Emp values (10, 5000, 'KING');
INSERT INTO Emp values (30, 4000, 'BLAKE');
INSERT INTO Emp values (10, 2000, 'CLARK');
INSERT INTO Emp values (20, 2000, 'JONES');
INSERT INTO Emp values (20, 3000, 'SCOTT');
INSERT INTO Emp values (20, 3000, 'FORD');
INSERT INTO Emp values (20, 1000, 'SMITH');
```

Есть запрос

```
SELECT max(salary), deptno, count(*) FROM Emp
GROUP BY Deptno
```

Который выводит номер департамента, максимальную зарплату, и количество человек в департаменте.
Как модифицировать запрос, таким образом, что бы вместо общего количества человек в департаменте выводилось количество  человек получающих максимальную запрплату в данном департаменте?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab1910/4

Comment: *вместо общего количества человек в департаменте выводилось количество человек получающих максимальную запрплату в данном департаменте* Получите эту максимальную зарплату в подзапросе, и замените звезду в аргументе на соотв. условие (равенство).

Comment: @Akina я пытался сделать как вы сказали, используя в count вместо звездочки следующее условие `q1.salary = (select max(q2.salary) from emp q2 WHERE q2.deptno = q1.deptno)` 
Но это не срабатывает :(

Comment: Подзапрос разместите в секции FROM.

Comment: @Akina такое решение я уже нашёл `SELECT 
    max(salary)
    , deptno
    , count(*) 
from Emp q1
where (salary, deptno) in(select max(salary), deptno from emp group by deptno)
group by deptno;`
Но теперь мне стал интересен ваш вариант с условием вместо звёздочки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(Emp.salary), deptno, COUNT(*), SUM(Emp.salary = max_salary.salary)
FROM Emp
JOIN ( SELECT max(salary) salary, deptno
       FROM Emp
       GROUP BY deptno
     ) max_salary USING (deptno)
GROUP BY Deptno;
```