# Как сделать поиск элемента, относительно другого?

Tags: mysql

Есть элемент таблицы, у которого есть поля сортировка, категория, просмотры. 
Известен id определенного элемента. Нужно получить элемент из той же категории что известный id, c большим количеством просмотров, и следующий по сортировке (т.е. сортировка больше)

Сделал следующий запрос, но совершенно не нравится:

```
select * from `tb` where 
`category` = (select `category` from `tb` where `id` = 1) 
and `sort` > (select `sort` from `tb` where `id` = 1)
and `view` > (select `view` from `tb` where `id` = 1)
order by `sort` asc
limit 1
```

Пример базы и запроса:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23b83ce/2

Comment: Если Вас интересует MySQL-реализация - зачем Вы даёте PHP-код и помечаете тему PHP-тегом? Уберите ненужное, и добавьте DDL таблиц, пример наполнения, исходные данные (скажем, id=5) и желаемый результат.

Comment: Вам не кажется вот этот фрагмент: ``where `sort`=$item[sort] ... and `sort`>$item[sort]``... ну скажем так - не совсем логичным? и вообще ставящим под сомнение утверждение, что *В 2 запроса это делается легко*.

Comment: Первый раз задаю вопрос по sql, попробую оформить нормально

Comment: Не могу найти справку для mysql... только оформление кода...

Comment: Ну [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1028493/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81) пример правильно оформленного запроса. Структура таблиц, данные, хорошо описанный (жале, не показанный таблицей) желаемый результат, и даже fiddle.

Comment: @Akina, Поправил, благодарю за поправления и наводку на сервис.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верно понимаю задачу, то запрос может быть таким:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tb t1, tb t2
WHERE t1.category = t2.category
  AND t2.id=1
  AND t1.sort > t2.sort
  AND t1.view > t2.view
ORDER BY sort ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

`t2` - это чисто получить запись с заданным `id`, так сказать, эталон и начало поиска. По `t1` будем искать. Отбираем в ней записи только с той же `category`, бОльшим `sort` и бОльшим `view`, далее сортируем по возрастанию `sort` и берём первую (т.е. ближайшую) запись.

Comment: Вроде то, благодарю!

Comment: А не будет это сильно бить по производительности? Ведь изначальный inner join (который был опущен обычным from) строит выборку n^2.

Comment: @Pavel Сервер практически никогда не выполняет запрос строго по тексту. Почитайте мануал, раздел [Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization.html), там много всякого интересного. А если начинает беспокоить производительность подобного запроса - ну вот  тогда, вероятно, и наступит пора подумать о правильных индексах и иных средствах оптимизации.

Comment: @Pavel И ещё одно Вы упустили - не указали точную версию сервера. Если она восьмая, то запрос будет выглядеть совершенно иначе.

Comment: Благодарю, совершенно не подумал бы, что могут быть различия в версиях и запросах для таких задач и базовых операторов. Почитаю.